# Expo Asset.fromModule().localUri returns null

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo (version 34.0.1) app with react native webview. I want to load my static website located at ./assets/webApp/index.html into this webview. I am trying to get the local uri path of the index.html file but when I do

```js
const localUri =  Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/webApp/index.html')).localUri
```

the localUri variable returns null. When I get `uri` instead of the `localUri`, i get a URI path to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code in `App.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset'

export default function App() {

    const { localUri } = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/webApp/index.html'))
    console.log(localUri) // Returns null

    return (
        <WebView
            style={styles.webView}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={ Platform.OS === 'android' ?
            { uri: localUri } : require('./assets/webApp/index.html') }
        />
    )
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~6.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-native-webview": "~5.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to download your asset first

```
this.HTMLFile = Asset.fromModule(require('./bibleWebView/dist/index.html'))

    // We never know, but localUri should always be there
    if (!this.HTMLFile.localUri) {
      Asset.loadAsync(require('./bibleWebView/dist/index.html')).then(() => {
        this.HTMLFile = Asset.fromModule(require('./bibleWebView/dist/index.html'))
        this.setState({ isHTMLFileLoaded: true })
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({ isHTMLFileLoaded: true })
    }
```

Comment: I get what you mean. But This is a react website I am loading in the web view. `index.html` is not the only file. `index.html` would call other JS files and images and CSS. Would this still work in that scenario?

Comment: Index.html should compress everything it needs in the same file, otherwise it won't work. Look at my repo https://github.com/bulby97/bible-strong/tree/master/src/features/bible/bibleWebView